# is it possible to get a grandchild dict key's value without iterating

Tags: python, xpath

given a dict what contains n number of dictionaries which contain n number of dictionaries etc.

```
foo = dict({"foo" : {"bar": {"baz": "some value"}}}
```

assuming `baz` could be anywhere in `foo` but that it will only occur once, is it possible without iterating to find if the value of the key "baz"? I'm thinking something xpath-ish. ie  `".//baz"`

```
if "baz" in foo: 
    bazVal = dict[path][to][baz]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without iteration/recursion.

```
>>> def search(d, baz):
...     if baz in d:
...         return d[baz]
...     for value in d.values():
...         if isinstance(value, dict):
...             ret = search(value, baz)
...             if ret:
...                 return ret
...
>>>
>>> foo = {"foo" : {"bar": {"baz": "some value"}}}
>>> search(foo, 'baz')
'some value'
>>> search(foo, 'spam')
>>>
```

Comment: thanks....i knew somewhere there'd have to be iteration but i was hoping for something under-the-hood like what xpath would provide in an etree

Answer (score 0):

With a standard dictionary, and not iterating?  No.

Answer (score 0):

Without iterating, not sure. With, you can use the following:

```
 d = dict({"foo" : {"bar": {"baz": "some value"}}})
 def myprint(d):
   for i in d.iteritems():
     if isinstance(i, dict):
       myprint(i)
     else:
       print i

 myprint(d)
```